# How many http requests can express.js handle?

Tags: node.js, http, express, server

I'm doing cost estimation for a university project, and I was wondering approximately how many requests can express.js handle for example on DigitalOcean's cheapest droplet (1gb memory, 1vCPU, 25GB SSD, 1TB transfer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load profile depends on the application. You should profile or load test the application to better understand if it's CPU bound, memory bound or I/O bound.